# Using title attr to store text

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items in an unordered list. Each `<LI>` item has a corresponding description that needs to be displayed when that element is selected. I was thinking of putting description into title attribute and then taking it from the on element click and rendering in the description container. However, I don't really want for it to show as tooltip when the mouse hovers over `<li>`. Is there a better alternative to title?

```
<li title="description here">My element</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in a `HTML5 data-* attribute`

```
<li data-title="description here">My element</li>
```

Doing so **will not** show the description as a **tool tip**..

`data-title` can be  any data-**yourname**

This can be accessed using either the `.attr()` or `.data()`

```
$('li').attr('data-title') ;
```

OR

```
$('li').data('title');
```

Comment: perfect, can I just leave it as data?

Comment: You can but it will not be validated... Your data attribute should start with   data-  .. So avoid using just data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DL` list with `DD` containing description and hidden by default when JS is enabled and visible when JS is disabled.

```html
<dl>
    <dt>My element</dt>
    <dd>Description here</dd>

    <dt>Another element</dt>
    <dd>Another description</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many attributes of a tag as you like. Feel free to define your own attributes without messing with the predefined ones.

For example:

`<li desc1="description here" desc2="Second desc here">My element</li>`

Access it as a normal attribute:

`$('li').attr('desc1')`

`$('li').attr('desc2')`

in your case it shoulld be like that:

```
$('li').bind('click', function(event) {
  var desc = $(event.target).attr('desc1');
});
```

'Standart' attributes should be used for their main purpose.
If developer needs his own attributes, he should freely define them.

One thing more: You can put even HTML into the attribute, just do not forget to escape wrapping delimiters (", ').  `desc1="<div class='alert'>description here</div>"`  will work fine.

Comment: would custom attribute tags pass as valid HTML?